# Post form in modal without redirect

Tags: jquery, post

I have a modal with a form which I want to submit without leaving or refreshing the page. I use this script:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    $.post("contact_submit.php", $("#contactForm").serialize());
});
```

This works to a certain extend, data arrives in the database. However, there are problems:

- under localhost it redirects me to http://localhost/dashboard/
- Form seems not to be posted once, but multiple times (many entries in database)

I tried `return false` and `e.preventDefault`, but none works for the redirection problem(in fact, the whole script stops working).

Any ideas for how to solve these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event of the form, not the click of the button, and also use `preventDefault()` on the passed event

Comment: Change the type of button from submit to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go using this approach. When `#id-of-form` is submitted then this is triggered. e.g.

```
$("#id-of-form").submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact_submit.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            /* load the response from contact_submit.php into div id results */
            $('#results').html(data);                           
        }
    }); 

});
```